# numpy: linspace calculation generating nan. How to remove point pair from both arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm curious if there's an elegant way to solve the problem below, preferably using as few lines of code as possible and is easy to remember, possibly a built-in numpy function?

Let's say I have a function f(x) and I want to be lazy and generate a np.linspace over an x range that purposely generates values of x where f(x) is not defined, so some of the points from my linspace correspond to "nan" in the my f(x) array.

My question is how to filter (or generate two new arrays) that only saves point pairs (x, f(x)), where f(x) != nan?

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-2,2,20)

with np.errstate(all='ignore'):
   fx = np.sqrt(x**2 - 1)

# here we can see "nan"
print(fx)

# want something here that removes 
#   (x[i], fx[i]) pair from arrays if x[i] has 'nan' as value
# <insert code>

plt.plot(x,fx)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't really any need to filter out the `nan`, they are simply not plotted.

[image]

If you want to filter them out, the line gets connected.

```
 plt.plot(x[~np.isnan(fx)],fx[~np.isnan(fx)])
```

[image]

Comment: what does the ~tilde do?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out:

```
X_ = [(X) for (X,FX) in zip(x,fx) if math.isnan(FX)==False]
FX_ = [(FX) for FX in fx if math.isnan(FX)==False]
```

`plt.plot(X_,FX_)`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
x = np.linspace(-2,2,20)
#print(x)
with np.errstate(all='ignore'):
   fx = np.sqrt(x**2 - 1)

# here we can see "nan"
#print(fx)

#   (x[i], fx[i]) pair from arrays if x[i] has 'nan' as value
# <insert code>
a=pd.DataFrame({'Column1':x[:],'Column2':fx[:],}).dropna(inplace=True)
print(a)
plt.plot(a.Column1,a.Column2)
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("fx")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-5, 5,100)

with np.errstate(all='ignore'):
   f1 = np.sqrt(x**2 - 1)

# filter nan based on f1 position
f2  = f1[~np.isnan(f1)]
x2  = x[~np.isnan(f1)]

plt.plot(x2,f2, '.')
```